# Compiling Word Count Map Reduce Example

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, javac, java-6

I have a problem compiling the Word Count Map Reduce example that comes with Hadoop.

I am getting the following error:

> WordCount.java:6: cannot access org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path bad class
>   file:
>   /home/john/Apps/hadoop-1.0.4/hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar(org/apache/hadoop/fs/Path.class)
>   class file has wrong version 50.0, should be 49.0

I am well aware that this suggests I am using the wrong version of Javac to compile the code. However I have updated to the latest version of the Sun Java 6 JDk and I call it explicitly like this:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_43/bin/javac -classpath ${HADOOP_HOME}/${HADOOP_CORE_JAR} -d wordcount_classes WordCount.java
```

And I still get this error. It doesn't make sense to me. I am not using a Java 5 compiler so why is javac insisting I should be using a class with version 49.0 ?

NOTE: The output of running
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_43/bin/javac -version
IS:

```
javac 1.6.0_43
javac: no source files
```

Followed by the Usage instructions.

Comment: What is the output of `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_43/bin/javac -version`?

Comment: Thanks Ericson, As you might expect it outputs: javac 1.6.0_43
javac: no source files. Followed by the Usage directions.

Comment: Try to add the target parameter: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_43/bin/javac -target 1.6 -classpath ${HADOOP_HOME}/${HADOOP_CORE_JAR} -d wordcount_classes WordCount.java